# ubuntu 4K resolution - tiny buttons and checkboxes problem

Tags: display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I'm having a built-in 4K display in my laptop. I have set the scaling factor in display to 2, so that the icons are scaled. However, in some applications I'm finding problems such as very tiny buttons and checkboxes.

One example for tiny buttons is the opencv imshow() terminal window and at the bottom of the window,, there are some numbers displayed, which I cannot see. Wherever there are checkboxes, it is very small such as checkboxes in vlc preferences settings.

I lowered the resolution but I got only uneven scaling, which is also difficult to work. If there is a way to increase the buttons and checkbox sizes in all the applications in Ubuntu, it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

[image]